# NodeJS - Logging - Request or Stack number in logging

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, stack

There 2 requests reaching to nodejs. Both are blocking requests.

I want to logs with request number I do not find any way to present request number

Each request call functions and functions have logs to debug data and DB response.

```
- (async) Authenticate Customer ID (function: async checkCumber()) (is Active, is Paid)
  - (async) Get Customer By Id (function: async getCustomer())
     - (async) Get Customer Vehicle by Customer Id (function: async getVehicleByCustomerId())
        - (async) Get Vehicle Details by Vehicle Id (function: async getVehicleByVehicleId())
```

Here is the output of console.log() of both requests.

> Customer Validated Customer Id "C2" (this log from request-1)
>
> Customer Detail found from DB (this log from request-1)
>
> Customer Validated Customer Id "C4" (this log from request-2)
>
> Customer 2 Vehicle found (this log from request-1)
>
> Customer Detail found from DB  (this log from request-2)
>
> Vehicles detail found (this log from request-1)
>
> Customer 2 Vehicle found (this log from request-2)
>
> Vehicles detail found (this log from request-2)

I want logs like

> Request 55: Customer Validated Customer Id "C2"
>
> Request 55: Customer Detail found from DB
>
> Request 56: Customer Validated Customer Id "C4"
>
> Request 55: Customer 2 Vehicle found
>
> Request 56: Customer Detail found from DB
>
> Request 55: Vehicles detail found
>
> Request 56: Customer 1 Vehicle found
>
> Request 56: Vehicles detail found

Generally, we do with Java code write thread number with log to easy to trace issues and debug code when got logs from production.

If there any tool or npm package suggest to me which gives me my desire log output.

Comment: you could into continuation-local-storage or cls-hooked npm package. It allows you to track an express request throughout its journey

Comment: @DhananjaiPai It is working for me thank you....

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Please add as an answer so other geeks can get the idea.

Comment: Sure, consider updating the answer below and adding the info you found and may be upvote if it helped. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could into continuation-local-storage or cls-hooked npm package. It allows you to track an express request throughout its journey

https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage